# Chance de number off significant digits in a text

Tags: python

I have a txt file as above:

Price: 1.340005666
Quant: 3.45600000934
Price: 3.43233
Quant: 7.0934

I read de txt file and send the text via e-mail, but I want to send via e-mail only 2 digits as above:

Price: 1.34
Quant: 3.45
Price: 3.43
Quant: 7.09

I can't change how the text is writed, but I trying to chance digits before send the e-mail.

The values are not in variable, but in a txt file created by another system.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code and what went wrong? [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Price= 1.340005666

Comment: Price=round(Price,2)

Comment: What about simple string formatting: `f'{1.340005666:.2f}'`? So if you have a variable `price` it would be `f'{price:.2f}'`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the question is simply asking to round the price to 2 dp.

if so, then this is all that is needed:

```py
price = 1.340005666

new_price = round(price, 2)
print(new_price)
```

result:

```
1.34
```

The OP can concatenate the email string and proceed from there.

Comment: the values are not in variables, but in a txt file as string

Comment: then the question is a different one:  Probably this, "How to extract a number from a text string ?"...

Comment: You would slice the `string` and take the `float`, but since there is no code to reproduce, it would be hard to show.   This generically works with the string you have `n = float(s[7:11])`, where `s` is the string.